# How to count number of success of a binomial sample in R?

Tags: r

I'm not used to R but what I want to do is this in pseudo code

```
T = 0
F = 0
for (i in 1:1000) {
  successCount <- count(rbinom(1,100,0.6)==1)
  if(successCount >= 59)
      T = T + 1
  else
      F = F + 1
}
```

Trying to run a simulation without rerun / map.

```
successCount <- count(rbinom(1,100,0.6)==1)
```

This part I've been searching but cant seem to find how to do this. Rest I think work

Comment: Though legal, it's really bad programming form to override the `T` and `F` constants (abbreviations for `TRUE` and `FALSE`, respectively) with you variables. In general, try not to override existing base functions, it can easily cause problems.

Comment: Did you check what `rbinom(1,100,0.6)` returns? Are you sure you want that? Also it is helpful if you can explain in plain words what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
table(replicate(1000,ifelse(sum(rbinom(100,1,0.6)==1)>=59,1,0)))
  0   1 
374 626
```

where 0 represents F and 1 represents T.

Comment: Another way of doing the same `table(replicate(1000, sum(rbinom(100,1,0.6))) >= 59)`. This avoids `ifelse`.